# how to use map function to split character, get min values, and store in a newly created pandas column

Tags: python, pandas, lambda

I clean up data from a csv file by splitting a character so that I get two numbers i.e., (750,755) instead of (750-755). I was successful in doing so. Now I am trying to get the min value i.e. (750) and create a new column called FICO.Score to store those min values. This is the part that I can't figure out, as I get a syntax error when I try to print out the new column.

```
import pandas as pd
loansData = pd.read_csv('https://spark-public.s3.amazonaws.com/dataanalysis/loansData.csv')

fc = loansData['FICO.Range']
fico = list(map((lambda x: x.split('-')), fc))
loansData['FICO.Score'] = list(map((lambda x: min(x), fico))

print loansData['FICO.Score']
```

Comment: Firstly you are missing a trailing parentheses on you line: `loansData['FICO.Score'] = list(map((lambda x: min(x), fico))` secondly even with this added you get a TypeError: `TypeError: map() must have at least two arguments.`

Comment: Actually you have 1 too many leading parentheses, it works if you do this: `loansData['FICO.Score1'] = list(map(lambda x: min(x), fico))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that the min value is always the first value in the `'min_val-max_val`' string then you can just use the vectorised `str` methods to split the string and take the first value and cast to `int64`:

```
In [14]:

loansData['FICO.Score'] = loansData['FICO.Range'].str.split('-').str[0].astype(np.int64)
loansData['FICO.Score']
Out[14]:
81174    735
...
55610    680
38576    675
3116     670
Name: FICO.Score, Length: 2500, dtype: int64
```

The reason you got an error is that you have an extra leading parenthesis:

```
In [19]:

loansData['FICO.Score1'] = list(map(lambda x: min(x), fico))
loansData['FICO.Score1']
Out[19]:
15867    715
94971    670
36911    665
41200    670
83869    735
53853    725
...
49957    685
23735    705
65882    740
55610    680
38576    675
3116     670
Name: FICO.Score1, Length: 2500, dtype: object
```

Note however that this still leaves you with a dtype of `object` which is a `str` which is not what you want